# What is the correct terminology for this kind of CSS declaration ".myClass div"?

Tags: css, terminology

What is the correct terminology when referring to a CSS declaration containing CSS combinators, such as:

```
.myClass div { ... }
```

Here I'm using a declaration which will apply styles to all `div` elements inside an element with the class `myClass`.

But that is irrelevant. I'm interested in knowing the correct terminology for a declaration which mentions parent selectors.

But what is the correct terminology for this sort of declaration?

Comment: Another useful resource: http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-terms-definitions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called Descendant Selectors, [see here for more information](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) and other terms

Just in case the W3 site ever goes down ;) here are the important parts:

> At times, authors may want selectors to match an element that is the
> descendant of another element in the document tree (e.g., "Match those
> EM elements that are contained by an H1 element").
>
> Descendant selectors express such a relationship in a pattern. A descendant
> selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by white space.
> A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an element B is
> an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

---

**Example** (also quoted from the site linked above):

For example, consider the following rules:

```
h1 { color: red }
em { color: red }
```

Although the intention of these rules is to add emphasis to text by changing its color, the effect will be lost in a case such as:

```
<H1>This headline is <EM>very</EM> important</H1>
```

We address this case by supplementing the previous rules with a rule that sets the text color to blue whenever an EM occurs anywhere within an H1:

```
h1 { color: red }
em { color: red }
h1 em { color: blue }
```

Answer (score 6):

They're called *descendant selectors*:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

> A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by
>   white space. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an
>   element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.